# Как сделать location.href с якорем и обновлением страницы?

Tags: javascript, html

как сделать location.href с якорем и обновлением страницы, то есть у нас есть :

```
document.location.href = '/stream#post_321';
```

Если этот код исполнить со страницы /stream - то страница не обновится, а лишь опускается якорь.

Можно ли как-то сделать чтоб страница и обновилась, а после сработал якорь на #post_321 ?

Comment: `document.location.reload()`

Comment: Не надо издеваться над страницей.

Comment: @ThisMan а можно как-то сразу сделать без обновления ибо я сразу сделал так, но оно несколько раз дергается и мне это не нравится                    document.location.reload()
document.location.href =  '/stream#post_321';

Comment: а если наоборот?

Comment: `document.location.assign('/stream#post_321')`

Comment: Вообще то всегда было `window.location`, а не `document`. Попробуйте консоль хрома использовать - очень информативно и удобно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно прямо в ссылке прописать якорь и событие onclick

```
<a href="#post_321" onclick="location.reload()">...</a>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]